# How to center TreeView item?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have TreeView and programmatically get SelectedItem.
So, i can get TreeViewItem from my TreeNode;

```
TreeViewItem visItem = rootItem;
            foreach (TreeNode item in parentStack)
            {
                TreeViewItem visItemTemp = (TreeViewItem)visItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);//get visual tree object
                if (visItemTemp != null)
                    visItem = visItemTemp;
             //   visItem.BringIntoView();//scroll to selected item

                //Point pos = visItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), TreeScroll);
                //Point pos = visItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), visItem);
                //double vo = TreeScroll.VerticalOffset + pos.Y - TreeScroll.ViewportHeight /2;
                //double vo1 = TreeScroll.VerticalOffset + pos.Y -TreeScroll.ViewportHeight / 2;

                //vo1 = Math.Abs(pos.Y);

                //TreeScroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(vo1);
                //TreeScroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(vo);
                Point pos = visItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), TreeScroll);
                double vo = TreeScroll.VerticalOffset + pos.Y - TreeScroll.ViewportHeight / 2;
                var vo1 = TreeScroll.ContentVerticalOffset + pos.Y;//(TreeScroll.ViewportHeight - (pos.Y))/2;//TreeScroll.VerticalOffset + pos.Y - TreeScroll.ViewportHeight ;
            //    if (vo1 < 0)
              //      vo1 = Math.Abs(vo1);
                //if (vo1 < 80)
                //    vo1 = 200;

                TreeScroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(vo);
                Console.WriteLine("vo:{0}", vo);
            }
```

I try a lot of ways, but it does not work well: i try to center my view at selected element.
Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: Can you write (or link) some example?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode